# Warning: urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: wp-query, warnings

I have posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11457701/wordpress-return-all-custom-post-types-within-given-categories) on StackOverflow (sorry for the cross link) and while I'm striving to find a solution to this, I stumbled across this warning :

> Warning: urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
>   /var/www/.../httpdocs/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 3192

And doing a backtrace, I find it originates in `query.php` :

**wp_includes/query.php**, *lines 1710...1712*

```
if ( isset( $t->rewrite['hierarchical'] ) && $t->rewrite['hierarchical'] ) {
     $q[$t->query_var] = wp_basename( $q[$t->query_var] );
}
```

Now, I get this error because one of my URL param is an array of categories, where I'm trying to search and return all product (custom post type) that has one or more of the defined categories assigned.

Why is WordPress trying to call `basename` on an array of `GET` parameter is beyond me. Anyone care to explain this to me? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what's happening, but I can guess based on a few context clues. That particular function is `parse_tax_query`. It appears to be checking if the taxonomy is hierarchical, I assume it's expecting a string that could possibly be a parent/child path of terms, so it uses basename to get the actual term queried- the next line is `$term = $q[$t->query_var];`

Comment: And what's the solution? I am having the same 'issue' when creating new WP_Query.

Comment: So the correct syntax that works for me in WP 3.6 is `'category__in' => $category` where `$category` is an array.