# Why can't I use an array of term slugs in WP_Query?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query

In `WP_Query`, a comma-separated list of term slugs works fine:

```
$query = new WP_Query ( array(  
     'customtaxonomy' => 'term1,term2'
) );
```

...but an array of slugs causes a warning:

```
$query = new WP_Query ( array(  
     'customtaxonomy' => array( 'term1', 'term2' )
) );
```

> **Warning:** urlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /path/to/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 3253

Another [WPSE post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/58341/3564) proposes that this could be WP looking for hierarchy in a hierarchical taxonomy, but I can't think of any way to make sense of this behaviour. Do you know why this is happening?

Answer (score 2):

If you read the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/wp_query#Taxonomy_Parameters) page carefully, you will see that taxonomy parameter `{tax}` (in your case it is `customtaxonomy`) takes only string value. Furthermore such taxonomy parameter is deprecated from version `3.1`. So in your case you have to pass `tax_query` array with `terms` array:

```
$query = new WP_Query ( array(  
    'tax_query' => array( 
        'terms' => array( 'term1', 'term2' )
    )
) );
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize that the taxonomy parameter is deprecated. Tangentially, writing a query string that would be parsable into `tax_query` seems quite complicated, if possible at all. (For example, I use a post listing shortcode with a `query` parameter.)

Comment: @supertrue it is good habit to read the codex first... ;)